# VBA Project in Outlook crashes intermittently

Tags: crash, outlook-addin, jet

Running an Outlook Add-in written in VBA sporadically crashed.  The point in the code where the failure occurs is random - and sometimes the program runs to completion.  The code also employs Excel, Word and the ODBC (Jet/Access); and when it did crash, it was usually around an SQL call.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be caused by 2 versions of Office/365 being on my machine: one was pre-loaded while the other, purchased by my company.

The flakey behavior appears to have been caused by Outlook, swapping between DLLs while running my AddIn.

To fix, in Windows Settings --> Applications

Searched for MS Office

Removed the earlier version.